# How good is Scheduling Messages with RabbitMQ (rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange) for production usage

Tags: rabbitmq, scheduling

Currently, we are planning to generate threshold of 20K notifications per minute and add delay to fetch notification status at few intervals like 2 mins, 5 mins, 1 hour and then 1 day if the status isn't final. 
I have done POC with 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/
it looks good but wanted to know real-time stats or any other suggestion before going live.

Comment: "wanted to know real-time stats or any other suggestion before going live" is too vague to provide feedback.

Comment: @LukeBakken, I saw in the github that "This plugin is considered to be experimental yet fairly stable and potentially suitable for production use as long as the user is aware of its limitations." 
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange
Just wanted to see if there are any improvements done on it or any implementation challenges.
Thanks.